# For every three sets $x,y,z$ we denote $\langle x,y,z\rangle=\{\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\}\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> For every three sets $x,y,z$ we denote $\langle x,y,z\rangle=\{\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\}\}$.
> Is the following statement **always** true: $$x=x_1\land y=y_1\land z=z_1\iff \langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle$$

I think the first direction is always true. So we want to check the implication $$x=x_1\land y=y_1\land z=z_1\Rightarrow\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle$$

Well, we obviously have $\{\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\}\}=\{\{x_1\},\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_1,y_1,z_1\}\}$ when $x=x_1, y=y_1, z=z_1$.

I am not so sure about the other direction, though. So the question is if:

$$\langle x,y,z\rangle=\langle x_1,y_1,z_1\rangle\Rightarrow x=x_1\land y=y_1\land z=z_1 $$ is true. This is equivalent to $$\{\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\}\}=\{\{x_1\},\{x_1,y_1\},\{x_1,y_1,z_1\}\}\Rightarrow x=x_1\land y=y_1\land z=z_1$$ I am not sure how to check this statement. In general two sets $A$ and $B$ are equal iff $x\in A \iff x\in B$. Not sure how to approach the problem. What's the correct way to show that it's **always** true?  Thanks!

Comment: Compare $\langle 1,1,2\rangle$ and $\langle 1,2,2\rangle$.  In these is $y=y_1$?  How do they look when written as sets?  Recall that $\{1\}=\{1,1\}$

Comment: @JMoravitz, But I am not sure if that's a counterexample for the second direction. The sets are not equal in that case, so the implication is still true.

Comment: @JMoravitz, my mistake!!! Sorry. And what was the motivation that led to you finding that counterexample? Thanks!

Comment: "*The sets are not equal in that case*"  Why do you say that?  Is it not the case that $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$ is equal to $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$?  Is it not the case that $\{\{1\},\{1,1\},\{1,1,2\}\}$ is equal to $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,2\}\}$?

Comment: "*What was the motivation that led to finding that counterexample?*"  It is clear that if $x,y,z$ are all unique that even after relabeling and rearranging how the set is written, you have $\{\{Y,a\},\{a\},\{z,a,Y\}\}$ you can pinpoint which element of this set was a one-element set... in this case $\{a\}$, and that one element in that one-element-set must have been $x$, despite our attempts to hide it by rearranging and relabeling.  Similarly we would have found what $y$ must have been equal etc...  The only problem then comes from what happens if some of the elements are equal.

Comment: All equal, well, no problem there... $\{\{x\},\{x,y\},\{x,y,z\}\}$ would have just been a one-element set and we would have been able to quickly determine that all of $x,y,z$ are equal.  The only remaining case to check is if two are equal, and noting there are different ways for that to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Collating comments to remove from unanswered queue:

Consider the counterexample of $\langle 1,1,2\rangle$ versus $\langle 1,2,2\rangle$

We have these are equal to $\{\{1\},\{1,1\},\{1,1,2\}\}$ and $\{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{1,2,2\}\}$ respectively, but we recall that we are working with sets and not multi-sets and as such these both contain redundancies that when simplified are both equal to $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$.  That is, despite $\langle 1,1,2\rangle = \langle 1,2,2\rangle$ by the given set definition we do not have the middle entries equal.

The similar attempt at a definition *does* work for tuples (*ordered pairs of two elements*) and is the standard definition by Kuratowski that we commonly use.  We can, despite obfuscation by relabling or rearranging or the like, figure out what $x$ is by looking at the set definition by it being the sole element of the element in the set which happens to itself be a one-element set, while $y$ would have to be the other element in a two-element set if it existed... or if there wasn't a two-element set then it would have to have been equal to $x$ as well.

The issue here is that although we can discern between $x,y,z$ in the case of $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ being a three-element set and so all of these being different, or in the case of $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ being a one-element set we can tell that they must all be the same... there is ambiguity in what happens if $\langle x,y,z\rangle$ is a two-element set.  We can tell that two of the elements must have been equal, but we can't tell which two.  We'll be able to unambiguously find what $x$ must have been equal to, again as there must have been a one-element set, and we'll have been able to determine what the element not-equal to $x$ must have been, but we would not be able to tell whether that not-equal element was $y$ or $z$ or both.